# How can I catch native thread creation in a Managed/Unmanaged DirectShow application?

Tags: multithreading, directshow, managed

I have a mixed mode 64-bit managed app that creates a DirectShow filtergraph via a managed interop assembly.  I need to catch the thread creation for one of the unmanaged filter threads (could hook Quartz.dll, but that is too painful).  Which SDK/C++ runtime functions should I put function breakpoints on (CreateThread, _beginthread, etc) -- or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to create some dummy DLL for your app, that implements DllMain and its 4 messages.  One of the messages, [DLL_THREAD_ATTACH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682583%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) would be the place to stick a breakpoint or whatever code.